# Is there a way to invoke a goal of a particular version of a Maven plugin?

Tags: maven

I would like to invoke a goal of a particular version in a Maven plugin from the command line.

How can this be achieved?

I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
mvn org.foo:my-plugin:1.2.3-SNAPSHOT:do-something
```

Comment: Why can't you specify the version of the plugin in the pom ?

Comment: Because this is a plugin which doesn't require a `pom.xml` file. Otherwise, what you suggest, would be the easiest thing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first guess is correct. The scheme for such a command is

```
mvn groupid:artifactid:version:goal
```

Example:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile
```

Comment: So right you are! I had misspelled my plugin's groupId. Thanks anyway.